# How to search with pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, pdf.js

I'm displaying a pdf file with pdf.js in my Ionic App. I do not use viewer.js and viewer.html, because I need a totally different layout. Now I have a custom search bar and I want to highlight terms in my pdf file. Is there a function I can invoke to do this?

I'm rendering the file like this:

```
$scope.renderPages = function(pdfDoc) {
    $scope.pdfFile = pdfDoc;
    for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++){
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then($scope.renderPage);
    }
}

$scope.renderPage = function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
    scale = document.getElementById('viewer').clientWidth / viewport.width;
    viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: ctx,
        viewport: viewport
    };

    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('viewer');
    canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

    page.render(renderContext);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="viewerContainer" style="padding-bottom: 100%; padding-top: 20px;">
    <div id="viewer" class="viewer-styles">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Depends what do you want to do with the results. If you just want to find a page, use page.getTextContent(). But if you want to display, check examples/components and use PDFFindController.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to understand PDFFindController but it seems to be complicated. Unfortunately, I didn't find any example how to use it. Do you know a good tutorial?

Comment: I don't think you need to understand the logic. Just find how it's used in web/ files.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Now I found the solution!

```js
var container = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');
var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');


var pdfViewer = new PDFViewer({ 
   container: container,
   viewer: viewer
});

$scope.pdfFindController = new PDFFindController({
   pdfViewer: pdfViewer
);

pdfViewer.setFindController($scope.pdfFindController);

container.addEventListener('pagesinit', function () {
    pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = 'page-width';                            
});

PDFJS.getDocument(MY_PATH_TO_THE_PDF).then(function (pdfDocument) {
    pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument);
});
```

Search for terms:

```js
$scope.pdfFindController.executeCommand('find', {
    caseSensitive: false, 
    findPrevious: undefined,
    highlightAll: true, 
    phraseSearch: true, 
    query: "myQuery"
});
```

And I had to import the viewer.js.

The code that I posted in the question is not needed anymore. The PDFViewer renders the pdf.

Comment: @chocolate_cake, this saved my day :) Did you find a way to identify the page number that contains the search results, in order to display only that page? Or, alternatively, to direct focus to the highlighted text? I can see both a matchCount and a pageMatches array defined in pdf_find_controller.js  (https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/58844381/), but I can't figure out how to access them; even after the document is loaded and the highlights are properly displayed, pdfFindController.matchCount returns zero. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @derelict! I'm really pleased that I could help you. I changed the pdfjs so that it just shows one page and I searched on this page (Reason: Permormance issues on mobile devices). I think the match array is the right way, but I didn't try to do this. Maybe you could get the scroll length by calculating pdfLength * pageNumber or something like that and scroll down?

Comment: Just curious, did you figure this out using some kind of documentation for the `viewer.js` tool?  I am having trouble using that tool outside of using the generic `viewer.html` page

Comment: What does `phraseSearch` do? and is there any way to highlight multiple words that aren't directly after each other?

Comment: Hi @Peter. I don't know any more what phraseSearch does. As I remind, all words should be highlighted when highlightAll is true. Take a look in the samples. May they could help you as they helped me.

Comment: where to find viewer.js?

Comment: I'm able to display a pdf using https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pdf-viewer-in-javascript--cms-32505 but not able to apply your search ability.  Browser shows error "PDFViewer is not defined" yet I am importing it like this <script src="../web/viewer.js"></script>

Comment: @user3217883 did you downloaded the library !, if yes you may need to check the files structure it may be changed, else create a question and post your code.

Comment: Is it me or does `setFindController()` no longer exists in the current version of `pdfjs-dist` ?

Comment: How to implement your answer into the code you explained in the question??

Comment: It looks like the setFindController method is deprecated. Use: `var findController = PDFViewer.findController; findController.executeCommand(...) `

Answer (score 7):

This is an old thread however I think people should know how the package works now. I have managed to make it work the following way. I was using an iframe to display the pdf.

```
const iframeDocument = document.getElementById('pdf-js-viewer').contentWindow;
let searchText = "TheTextYouWantoToHighlight";

iframeDocument.PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.findController.executeCommand('find', {
    caseSensitive: false, 
    findPrevious: undefined,
    highlightAll: true, 
    phraseSearch: true, 
    query: searchText
})
```

With the latest version of pdfjs, this works but gives error in console to use dispatch event. This code will remove that error and works as expected.

```
const iframeDocument = document.getElementById('pdf-js-viewer').contentWindow;
let searchText = "TheTextYouWantoToHighlight";
iframeDocument.PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.dispatch('find', {
    caseSensitive: false,
    findPrevious: undefined,
    highlightAll: true,
    phraseSearch: true,
    query: searchText
});
```