# How to highlight text with PDFJS?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, mobile, pdf.js

I'm creating an app that shows a PDF file among others. I need to implement a search functionality so that I can search for terms in the pdf file. To display the file I'm using PDFJS.

In the pdfjs library are some examples including the components example that renders a page and you can mark the text (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components).

But when I'm trying to use this code in my app I'm getting the error that `PDFJS.DefaultTextLayerFactory()` is undefined. I include these three files:

```
<script src="lib/pdfviewer/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="lib/pdfviewer/pdf.worker.js"></script>
<script src="lib/pdfviewer/pdf_viewer.js"></script>
<script src="lib/pdfviewer/compatibility.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does PDFJS not know `DefaultTextLayerFactory`?

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Just FYI: "pdf_viewer.js" is not included in the stable release, cloning the pdf.js Github repo and going through the gulp installation will get you the file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot to include viewer.js

How to search for terms you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770115/4465464)