# AngularJS - highlight text of an existing pdf file in frontend/Browser

Tags: angularjs, pdf

I have found the library

[PDF creation](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/)

With this library it is possible to create different styles of pdf documents.
My question would be if there is a possibility to mark text (and maybe add a link to this marked text) of an existing pdf file with AngularJS?
Or is there any workaround to do this?

Comment: I think that If the pdf is already created you can not modify it but if you are generating the pdf, yes you can do both.

Comment: If you use PdfJS to display the  generated PDF file, it would probably be possible but what are your expected results? That thte file be downloaded by the user or uploaded to the server? Or else? See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722961/how-to-highlight-text-with-pdfjs) and [this librairy](https://pdf-highlighter.com/docs/Highlighting_PDF_Viewer.html)

Comment: You can check this http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/html2pdf/showcase_supported_html.html but it's working properly in only chrome & firefox, not in IE. If you want crossbrowser solution go for html2canvas & then convert that canvas to pdf using jsPDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit too broad as is - not sure what you mean by "mark" - do you mean highlighted in some way or actually selected?

Anyhow, firstly to get to the correct page -- you can use fragment identifiers in hyperlinks to link to a specific page in a PDF via the `page` parameter. e.g.

```
<a href="file.pdf#page=1">page 1</a>
<a href="file.pdf#page=2">page 2</a>
```

If you want to highlight a specific section of a page, via a hyperlink, you can use the `highlight` parameter, note you must also set the page to use the highlight parameter. e.g.

```
<a href="file.pdf#page=1&highlight=10,10,50,50">page 1 - highlight</a>
```

The rectangle values are integers in a coordinate system where 0,0 represents the top left, and the values are given in the order lt, rt, top, btm.

One can also open a PDF file to a "Named Destination", that is a named section in the document via the `nameddest` parameter. e.g.

```
<a href="file.pdf#nameddest=mysection">my section</a>
```

This is great as it doesn't matter if pages are inserted, removed etc as the section will always be correctly linked.

You can read about [Named Destinations here](http://archimedespalimpsest.net/Documents/External/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf#page=583) and also the [various Parameters for Opening PDF Files](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=5)