# Hightlight text in pdf using javascript(In angular app)

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf.js

I am trying to highlight text in pdf. I am using PDF.Js in angular but unable to find the way to highlight text in angular using the same java-script library.

Actually I want to start highlighting a text from a paragraph then I want to highlight each word one by one util end of the page.

I went through so many links but didn't find any solution or thought to do this.

I most closes link which I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501417/how-to-search-with-pdf-js/39770115#39770115) but it's also not working in angular app and it's not meeting my requirement.

Comment: Can you please add the code you've tried as well? Maybe create a sample StackBlitz to work with.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I created a plunker but it's not working due to a dependency  https://next.plnkr.co/edit/pYi2vydBVVb0T7G9?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview

Comment: Try [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) You can add your dependencies in the Dependencies section on the left hand side.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Firstly I tried in StackBlitz but it's showing error while adding pdfjs-dist dependency.