# How to use PDFFindController (pdf.js) inside react-pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js, react-pdf

I want to use `PDFFindController` from `pdf.js` inside React library `react-pdf`.

`react-pdf` uses `pdf.js` under the hood I don't want to spend time building from zero the search functionality and I think that using `PDFFindController` would be very time-saving.

However, I don't really know if it is even possible to use the `pdf.js` module from `react-pdf`

Related posts:

- [How to search with pdf.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501417/how-to-search-with-pdf-js)

Comment: I solved the problem of searching inside a PDF by gathering all text items from all PDF pages `pdf.getPage(1).then(getTextContent).then()` and search text using javascript